# In php, should curly brackets be used even in short conditional statements?

Tags: php, coding-style, conditional-statements

In PHP, I do know curly brackets are not *required* for one-statement conditionals. But **this question is about good coding style**. (Of course when talking about style, it's usually better to just use whichever style is consistent within the project, but let's ignore that for this question.)

So: Is it better form to enclose any conditional statements in curly brackets, or is it better (e.g. more clean) to not use brackets in simple conditions:

E.g. this:

```
if (!file_exists($templatefile)) {
   throw new Exception('Template file does not exist');
}
```

or this:

```
if (!file_exists($templatefile))
    throw new Exception('Template file does not exist');
```

Are there any common consistent good practices for this, or is it just up to personal preferences?

Comment: Stick to the rules of `good 'ol programming practices`  Use curly braces. You won't regret it later

Comment: For a while back I've converted my active projects to use these brackets everyhere (same with loops ofcourse). I feel this is better readable and ofcourse it prevents potential errors.

Comment: [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.control-statements.if-else-elseif), [Pear](http://pear.php.net/manual/es/standards.control.php), [cakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html#control-structures) ... kind of general agreement here : always use curly brackets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen way too many mistakes by people who do not use the curly brackets and then, later on, add an additional command and forget to wrap it.

My attitude is to wrap it for readability and future extensibility.

Comment: Yes, this would be my thinking too. Not enclosing is inconsistent with rest of the code, so it may lead to accidental problems, and possible debugging trouble.

Comment: It seems a [PHP Standards Recommendation](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/psr-huh/) also declares this in [PSR-2 5. Control Structures section](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#5-control-structures): *"The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. This standardizes how the structures look, and reduces the likelihood of introducing errors as new lines get added to the body."* Maybe this information could be included in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

One rule in good coding style is: Avoid distraction. So having a common way to do this - regarless of single- or mutliple-lines is the way to go:

```
if (!file_exists($templatefile)) {
   throw new Exception('Template file does not exist');
}
```

Sure, this *is* subjective (but that's a problem with your question), not all programmers are distracted by that. But by fact, your version control system will be. If you need to change a single-line if-block into a multiline one, do you need to touch the if condition? Hell no, because it did not change, right? But if you don't use the brackets, you still need to touch that line. That's what I would call distraction as well. So this is the *less* subjective argument to give.

As you can imagine, there are other arguments you can foster this approach with, like when you need to debug code and you need to switch from one to mutli-line for various changes etc. pp. So keep it aligned in your whole codebase, if it is the if block, it is the if block.

For the fun, the always throw "if" block:

```
if (!file_exists($templatefile)); {
   throw new Exception('Template file does not exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depend from developer to developer, it all up to you.
Just follow any one approch in your code, do not mix it up which would create problems in future